# How to prevent Visual Studio 2017 from adding log files into solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a C# .Net Core project and when I run this project the executable creates log file in it working directory which is same as project directory (where .csproj and other files are placed)[image: it looks like so]

It is a rolling file, so every day it creates a new file with Date in the file name.

**Problem is**: Visual Studio adds this files into solution automatically:[image]

How can I prevent this behavior? (This files are already in .tfignore file for TFVC but of course it has no impact on VS behavior).

UPDATE: I can exclude it from project manually but I don't like to do it every day.

Comment: What Logging Framework are you using?

Comment: @Nekeniehl Serilog

Comment: You can give different path to log files, out of the current project folder so that those are not created inside the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

1. Open your .csproj xml file
2. Add new section:

`<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="log*.txt" />
 </ItemGroup>`

3. Enjoy you work!